# Android onClick Not Getting View

Tags: android, event-handling

I'm trying to separate the event handling codes from my `MainActivity` class. Therefore, I've made a class called `ButtonHandler` that implements `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public class ButtonHandler implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    EditText txtCorpoToday = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCorpoToday);
    txtCorpoToday.setText("changing text");
}
```

But for some strange reason the app crushes in the `emulator`. I'm trying to find out where the problem is but the `logcat console` is giving me this error:

```
7-22 01:11:58.669    2823-2839/android.process.acore I/ContactLocale﹕ AddressBook Labels [en-US]: [, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, Α, Β, Γ, Δ, Ε, Ζ, Η, Θ, Ι, Κ, Λ, Μ, Ν, Ξ, Ο, Π, Ρ, Σ, Τ, Υ, Φ, Χ, Ψ, Ω, , А, Б, В, Г, Д, Ђ, Е, Є, Ж, З, И, І, Ї, Й, Ј, К, Л, Љ, М, Н, Њ, О, П, Р, С, Т, Ћ, У, Ф, Х, Ц, Ч, Џ, Ш, Щ, Ю, Я, , א, ב, ג, ד, ה, ו, ז, ח, ט, י, כ, ל, מ, נ, ס, ע, פ, צ, ק, ר, ש, ת, , ا, ب, ت, ث, ج, ح, خ, د, ذ, ر, ز, س, ش, ص, ض, ط, ظ, ع, غ, ف, ق, ك, ل, م, ن, ه, و, ي, , ก, ข, ฃ, ค, ฅ, ฆ, ง, จ, ฉ, ช, ซ, ฌ, ญ, ฎ, ฏ, ฐ, ฑ, ฒ, ณ, ด, ต, ถ, ท, ธ, น, บ, ป, ผ, ฝ, พ, ฟ, ภ, ม, ย, ร, ฤ, ล, ฦ, ว, ศ, ษ, ส, ห, ฬ, อ, ฮ, , ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅇ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅋ, ㅌ, ㅍ, ㅎ, , あ, か, さ, た, な, は, ま, や, ら, わ, #, ]
07-22 01:20:28.870    2823-2830/android.process.acore I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
07-22 02:12:42.475    2823-2837/android.process.acore V/BackupServiceBinder﹕ doBackup() invoked
07-22 02:12:42.477    2823-2837/android.process.acore E/DictionaryBackupAgent﹕ Couldn't read from the cursor
07-22 04:29:17.419    2823-2830/android.process.acore I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
```

Finally, I'm doing this because as the app is growing, I find it the my `MainActivity` class is getting bloated which is messy. What are the best approach to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You trying to initialize `EditText` with wrong `View`.
`OnClick(View v)` where `v` is `Button` or othere `View` that was pressed. And it's cant contains `EditText` inside itself. If you work in `Fragment` try in `onCreateView`

```
View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.yours_layour, null);
EditText txtCorpoToday = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCorpoToday);
```

Or in `Activity` in `onCreate`

```
EditText txtCorpoToday = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCorpoToday);
```

Comment: I can't seem to invoke `getActivity()` since I'm on a separate class.

Comment: so you need to use `Context` instead `getActivity()`

Comment: All my `View` are existing already so I'm not sure if I have to inflate it again? Also, I'm just feeding the `ButtonHandler` class the instance of `EditText` coming from `onCreate` from my Fragments. Is this going to be a good approach?

Comment: Not  really understand your action, can you show code example?

Comment: I just fed my `ButtonHandler` class the `EditText` I needed like this:

          `public ButtonHandler(EditText corpo, EditText ywc, EditText mlmF, EditText mlmI){...}` ;)

Comment: you need to feed only `ButtonHandler (Context context)` then use all you need inside this class

Answer (score 0):

findViewById should be used to find a view in its parent. When onClick is called v will be your button that is clicked.